# Find possible combinations of r elements in given array of size n with group

Tags: php

Everyone knows finding possible combinations of r elements in given array of size n algorithm but I need even further beyond from that.

I have an array of items. These items is array and has id, name, group_id bla bla bla.

I have to calculate possible combinations with different group_id. If Items have same group_id, they can't create combinations.

This is my function for calculation all possible combinations;

```
private function calculateComb(array $temp, int $start, int $end, int $index, int $size)
    {
        try {
            if ($index === $size) {
                $this->groups[$size]['combinations'][] = $temp;
                return;
            }
            for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
                $temp[$index] = $this->combinationItems[$i];
                $this->calculateComb($temp, $i + 1, $end, $index + 1, $size);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I tried to create a new function for calculation possible combinations with group_id;

```
private function calculateCombinations(array $temp, int $start, int $end, int $size, int $index, array &$groupIds)
    {
        try {
            if ($index === $size) {
                $this->groups[$size]['combinations'][] = $temp;
                unset($groupIds[$index]);
                return;
            }
            for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
                if (in_array($this->combinationItems[$i]['group_id'], $groupIds)) {
                    $this->calculateCombinations($temp, $i + 1, $end, $size, $index, $groupIds);
                } else {
                    $temp[$index] = $this->combinationItems[$i];
                    $groupIds[$index] = $this->combinationItems[$i]['group_id'];

                    $this->calculateCombinations($temp, $i + 1, $end, $size, $index + 1, $groupIds);
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

But this isn't working. Do you have an idea?

Array Example;

```
[
    [
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Test',
        'group_id': 1
    ], [
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Test2',
        'group_id': 1
    ], [
        'id': 3,
        'name': 'Test3',
        'group_id': 2
    ],
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found my solution again :)

```
private function calculateCombinations(array $temp, int $start, int $end, int $size, int $index, array &$groupIds)
    {
        try {
            if ($index === $size) {
                $this->groups[$size]['combinations'][] = $temp;
                $groupIds = [];
                return;
            }
            for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
                if (in_array($this->combinationItems[$i]['group_id'], $groupIds)) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    $temp[$index] = $this->combinationItems[$i];
                    $groupIds[$index] = $this->combinationItems[$i]['group_id'];

                    $this->calculateCombinations($temp, $i + 1, $end, $size, $index + 1, $groupIds);
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### solution for 2-element combinations

I don't know if you want a fancy solution, but this is probably a very simple one, essentially, what you do is a join on different group_id. The following is essentially a nested loop join. If you want/need to be more efficient/faster, there may be different join algorithms better suited, but I think nested loop join is quite efficient in this case.

nested loop join:

```
$output = [];
foreach($array as $left) {
    foreach($array as $right) {
        if($left['group_id'] != $right['group_id']) { // <-- join condition
             // create output, you probably want something else here...
             $output[] = ['left' => $left, 'right' => $right];
        }
    }
}
```

this creates all combinations: if (a,b) is a combination, (b,a) is a combination too.
if this is not what you want, you can include the key as well:

```
// ...
foreach($array as $lid => $left) { // <-- notice the l(eft) id
    foreach($array as $rid => $right) { // <-- notice r(ight) id
        if($lid < $rid && $left['group_id'] != $right['group_id']) {
           // ^^^^^^^ this ensures only one of the two combination will be joined
        }
    }
}
```

(edit ...)

### `k`-element combinations, where `k` == number of groups

not much explanation for now, if you *need* explanation, please comment.
this code might have minor bugs in them though, didn't test it.

1. build an array (`$grouped`), where each element is a an array containing items with the same group_id, so essentially

   ```
   $grouped = [];
   foreach($array as $item) {
       if(empty($grouped[$item['group_id']]) $grouped[$item['group_id']] = [];
       $grouped[$item['group_id']][] = $item; 
   }
   ```
2. take one element of each group, recursively:

   ```
   $grouped = array_values($grouped); // this simplifies keys

   function get_combinations($grouped, $i) {
       // in the k-th group, return all elements
       if(count($grouped)-1 == $i) {
           $ret = [];
           foreach($grouped[$i] as $item) {
               $ret[] = [$item];
           }
           return $ret;
       }

       // in the $i-th group ($i < k), build combinations of each element
       // in i-th group with every combination given from sub-call
       $subcombinations = get_combinations($grouped, $i+1);
       $result = []; // <--- REFERENCED LINE ...
       foreach($grouped[$i] as $item) {
           foreach($subcombinations as $comb) {
               $result[] = array_merge([$item], $comb);
           }
       }
       // return new combinations
       return $result;
   }

   $combinations = get_combinations($grouped, 0);
   ```

now, this is probably highly inefficient for very large arrays, if many massive groups are contained.

### all combinations with at least one item

if you also want to calculate combinations, that have less then `k` elements, you would replace the referenced line (see REFERENCED LINE in the code above) with

```
// add combinations without current group to result
// also add single-element combinations where element is from current group
$result = array_merge($subcombinations, get_combinations([$grouped[$i]],0));
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution but it has a problem, It only works for 2 size combinations. If I want to find 3 or more size combinations, it won't work. Thanks.

Comment: apparently I misunderstood your problem description then ;o)

Comment: Thank you very much but It's highly inefficient for very large arrays as you said and I must calculate possible combinations for very large arrays. It seems finding all possible combinations then checking these combinations will be more efficient :)

Comment: doubtful, but I'm interested in the solution at the end, if you would provide it. Unless of course you use some short cut like only using the ids instead of the items themselves (which is also something you could do with my solution) and only expanding them into items when needed.

Comment: found a way to group combinations :)